# Install a font with several styles in Inno Setup

Tags: fonts, styles, installation, inno-setup

Assume that there is a font that has several styles. Something like, NewFontNormal.ttf, NewFontBold.ttf, NewFontItalic.ttf and so on. Who can I install them in a way that after installation, I have **NewFont** in the fonts folder which all of its styles are embedded?

I tried the below scripts, but doesn't work:

```
[Files]
Source: "NewFontBold.TTF"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall  
Source: "NewFontItalic.TTF"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall  
Source: "NewFontNormal.TTF"; InstallFont:"NewFont" DestDir: "{fonts}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

if the **InstallFont** is written for all of font files entry, I don't get the proper result.

Any Idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install each font as individual then you need to add all entries like this in script

```
[Files]
Source: "OZHANDIN.TTF"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "Oz Handicraft BT"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

If you want to install  fonts  NewFontNormal.ttf, NewFontBold.ttf, NewFontItalic.ttf and so on as a single font (NewFont).

For this you need make single font manually And then use this NewFont file in files sections in combination with fontinstall..

And also please do refer FontInstall parameter in files section of inno setup.